# Take ownership of entire drive?

Tags: windows-7, ownership

I bought a new pc and installed my old HDD as secondary drive , how can I take ownership of all files and folder on that harddrive.

I remember there was some commandline tool icals or something which could do that recursivly.

Comment: Probably something like `cacls c:\ /T /E /G Everyone:F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I remember there was some commandline
>   tool icals or something

**CACLS.exe**

More info here:

**[Display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html)**

Comment: yes, that was it, thanks ill figure it out from here

Comment: you're more than welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`icacls.exe`](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html).

You can also use the older `cacls.exe`, but watch out. `cacls /G` will overwrite the entire ACL by default, which never seems to be what I want, so you have to pass `/E` to "edit" the ACL. On `icacls /grant` the behavior is reversed: edit by default, pass `:r` to replace the entire ACL.

`icacls` also supports setting the object/container inherit flags (`cacls` does not), but you probably don't care about that right now.